# Freeform online signing field-type options

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

Are there (3rd party) plugins for Freeform where you can add an online-signing field type?

Something like approve.me or docusign?
https://www.approveme.com/gravity-forms-signature/

If not, are there any API services which you would recommend/work best with FreeForm and EE, so we can create a custom plugin/addon?